# how to display data using separate tables in codeigniter view

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, view

I am still new in CodeIgniter and I want to separate the grades by semester and school year in different tables. How can I do that?

Here is my model:

```
public function result_getGrades($studentid)
    {
            $sql="  SELECT g.studentid, sb.subjectcode, s.description, si.firstname,sb.module, sb.sy, sb.sem, g.final 
                    FROM grades g 

                    JOIN subjectblocking sb ON g.blockcode=sb.blockcode

                    JOIN subjects s ON sb.subjectcode=s.subjectcode

                    JOIN studentinfo si ON g.studentid=si.studentid
                    WHERE g.studentid='$studentid'
                    ORDER BY sb.sem DESC, sb.sy DESC;
                    ";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $result->result();
            return $result;   
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

                    <tr>
                       <th>SY</th>
                       <th>SEM</th>
                       <th>SUBJCODE</th>
                       <th>SUBJECT DESCRIPTION</th>
                       <th>GRADE</th>
                    </tr>

                <?php foreach ($result as $row){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->sy;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->sem;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->subjectcode;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->description;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->final;?></td>
                    </tr>           
                <?php } ?>
```

I do hope somebody can help me in this problem. I badly need a solution for this. Thanks in advance!

By the way, here is my controller:

```
public function getGrades() 
{
        $studentid = $this->session->userdata('studentid');
        $data['studentid'] = $studentid;
        $this->load->view('layout/navbar');

        $this->load->model('Umodel');
        $data['result'] = $this->Umodel->result_getGrades($studentid); 
        $this->load->view('pages/grades', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer_student');
}
```

This is what the table should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkqjo.jpg

Comment: by separating the grades you mean two different tables with same grades? How are these in your database?

Comment: @ValentinValentin no, what i mean is to separate the grades into different tables and each table is sorted according to semester and school year. :)

Comment: wheres your Controller?

Comment: can you provide a sample of how your end result should look like?

Comment: I added already the controller and the link on how the table should be like @CodeGodie

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting up your data you could create views.

```
    CREATE VIEW 2015_Fall AS
    SELECT g.studentid, sb.subjectcode, s.description,
           si.firstname,sb.module, sb.sy, sb.sem, g.final
    JOIN subjectblocking sb ON g.blockcode=sb.blockcode
    JOIN subjects s ON sb.subjectcode=s.subjectcode
    JOIN studentinfo si ON g.studentid=si.studentid
    WHERE g.studentid='$studentid'
    AND  sb.sem = 'Fall' AND sb.sy='2015'
    ORDER BY g.final DESC;
```

This will create a view for Fall that will let you view the data as if it were a separate table.  However your data is still localized in the same tables.  You just have a separate view of your data.  You would want to create one of these for each semester/year.  You can sort and order the view as if it were a normal table.

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange your results to create a nice array in your controller, then send that array to your view for easier parsing. Try this:

Controller:

```
public function getGrades() {
    $studentid = $this->session->userdata('studentid');
    $data['studentid'] = $studentid;
    $this->load->view('layout/navbar');

    $this->load->model('Umodel');
    $result = $this->Umodel->result_getGrades($studentid);
    $final = array();
    $final["semesters"] = array();
    foreach ($result as $res) {
        if (!isset($final["semesters"][$res->sem])) {
            $final["semesters"][$res->sem] = array();
        }
        array_push($final["semesters"][$res->sem], $res);
    }
    $data['result'] = $final;

    $this->load->view('pages/grades', $data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer_student');
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($result['semesters'] as $sem) { ?>
    <table class = "table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>SY</th>
            <th>SEM</th>
            <th>SUBJCODE</th>
            <th>SUBJECT DESCRIPTION</th>
            <th>GRADE</th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($sem as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row->sy; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->sem; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->subjectcode; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->description; ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->final; ?></td>
            </tr>           
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

<?php } ?>
```